# How does the C++ code `x.erase(std::remove(x.begin(), x.end(), ' '), x.end())` work?

Tags: c++, c++11

The thing is I usually would use a for loop to handle this kind of thing but this method seems to be much more efficient. The documentation on cplusplus was a bit hard to comprehend for me.

```
std::string no_space(std::string x)
{
    x.erase(std::remove(x.begin(), x.end(), ' '), x.end());
    return x;
}
```

Comment: See the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Comment: See [Erase-remove idiom in C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

Answer (score 3):

The function `std::remove(x.begin, x.end), ' ')`moves elements to the end of the string and function `std::erase` actually deletes the elements that were moved to the end of the string.
You can also read more about this in the documentation [enter link description here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

There is the same example like you.

Comment: `std::remove` doesn't move anything to the end of the string. You should read the documentation you linked.

Answer (score 2):

`std::remove` moves all spaces to the end of the string and returns the iterator to the first space. Then `string::erase` removes from that first space till the end of the string.

This is a simplistic description, as commenters duly noted, make sure you read the documentation for these functions.

Comment: It is more correct to say that `remove` moves all non-spaces to the beginning of the string and returns an iterator to the end. The elements past the end may be in a moved from state; in this case clearly copy and move are the same for characters but this statement generalizes correctly.

Comment: You have a gold badge in the C++ tag so I'm a little surprised you don't know how `std::remove` works.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Post your own answer and refrain from personality attacks.

Comment: I'm just suggesting you could edit your answer to reflect how that algorithm actually works. This "move to the end" misinformation doesn't help anyone.

Comment: By the way, no offense was meant so I apologize. I have just seen too many questions and answers that assume `std::remove` works like a partition. That's not in the language standard and none of the major library implementations are written that way..

Comment: @Blastfurnace No worries.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down some

```
std::remove(x.begin(), x.end(), ' ')
```

This goes through all the elements of `x`, and overwrites any spaces with the next non-space. It returns the position one beyond the last non-space character. Importantly it does not change the `size` of `x`. Imagine the return value is assigned to a `std::string::iterator it`. From `it` to the end of `x` the elements are in a valid but unspecified state.

```
x.erase(it, x.end());
```

This removes elements from `x`, starting with the position returned by `remove`. This eliminates all the "valid but unspecified state" values from the end of `x`, which were left behind by `remove`.